# my live git-hub page is just showing the html aspect of my code despite working fully when i hosted it locally on vs code. why is that?

Tags: git, github, tailwind-css, github-pages

im using tailwind framework at the moment and both my html and css file is inside my docs folder. ive configured my github to look through the docs folder instead of the root folder . with that already done my live github page is just showing plain html stuffs. its incomplete

take a look at the link to my respository and see if theres anything I'm missing       https://vo-ke.github.io/Loopstudios-landing-page/

Comment: the above link is to the live-page this is to the respository  [ https://github.com/vo-ke/Loopstudios-landing-page ]

Comment: Trying to serve anything above `/Loopstudios-landing-page/` via `../` would not work since ` https://vo-ke.github.io/` does not serve the repository.

Comment: @Wongjn  emmm i actually dont understand what you just said but this is the link to my repository  [ https://github.com/vo-ke/Loopstudios-landing-page ] take a look at it and see if there's anything  i did wrong coz the live page on github is not displaying any pictures at the moment

Comment: You need to serve the images from `https://vo-ke.github.io/Loopstudios-landing-page/`, not from `https://vo-ke.github.io/` as you are trying to do with the `../` paths. Have the images inside `docs` and adjust your paths as needed.

Comment: thanks so muchhhhhhh you're literally a life-saver

Comment: @Wongjn it works perfectly fine now. thanks once more. you on twitter? let me follow you